# zindex for jquery.alert is not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I am using the jquery.alerts.js to create a "Confirm" box. I have a masked background so that the user does not do anything else on the page until he says "yes/No" on the confirm box.

The confirm box works great in Firefox but in IE it pop ups behind the GreyMask and not on top of it.

Any idea how to fix this for IE?

Thanks

Comment: could you show us an example (the css elements involved)

Comment: @Mithil did any of the answers below help you?

Comment: I asked the question 1 year back and don't really remember how I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In IE7 the z-index does not always work as expected. Try setting a high z-index for the popup parents also.

See [this link](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a somewhat similar issue. I tried all sorts of things. In the end I ended up with three things that together fixed it:

```
var zIndexNumber = 1000;
$('div, li, ul').each(function() {
    $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
    zIndexNumber -= 10;
});
```

Try pasting that in your javascript/jquery. It'll cycle through and set the z-index of every element. That way you can set your grey box to anything over 1000 and it should show.

Also, make sure you have position correct and the doctype correct. IE is picky.